# Is it possible to retrieve SQL result grouped as a list of lists

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have the following 3 tables as shown below and want to retrieve a List> in C# where each List holds all images within a group.

Can this be done with Entity Framework (or SQL) or do I have to iterate through a for loop and group them in C#?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Linq supports `Group by` clausule. You can retreive it in this way (via EF):

```
var imagesGrouped = dbContext.ImageGroupImages
                             .Include("Image") // include image nav property
                                               // if lazy loading is on                                 
                             .GroupBy(imgGr => imgGr.ImageGroupId)
                             .ToList();

foreach (var group in imagesGrouped)
{
   Console.WritLine("group: {0}, images: {1}",
                    group.Key,
                    string.Join(",", group.Select(img => img.Id)));
}
```

You can also convert it to list of lists:

```
var result = imagesGrouped.Select(group => group.ToList()).ToList();
```

but int that case you loose `Key` so you don't know of what group the list is corresponding to.

Answer (score 0):

With `LINQ`:

```
var result = from igi in imageGroupImages
             join i in images on igi.ImageID equals i.ID
             join ig in imageGroups on igi.ImageGroupID equals ig.ID
             select new
             {
                 ImageID = i.ID,
                 ImageUrl = i.Url,
                 GroupID = ig.ID,
                 GroupTitle = ig.Title
             } into s
             group s by new { s.GroupID, s.GroupTitle } into gr
             select new 
             { 
                 gr.Key.GroupID, 
                 gr.Key.GroupTitle, 
                 Images = gr.Select(c => new 
                                         { 
                                             c.ImageID, 
                                             c.ImageUrl 
                                         }) 
             };
```